# How can I sort two column read from txt file using python?

Tags: python, sorting, memory, tensor

I want to sort my txt file data using python but problem is it is given memoryerror. The txt-file data size is 3gb and my ram size is 8 gb. The txt-file data is integers. Like:

```
1 0 3 1 1
2 1 2 1 1
1 2 1 3 1
.........
```

Now, Is there any option to sort this txt file without store it in memory? please help.

Comment: *sort this txt file without store it in memory*?

Comment: Are you saying that the text file is just one long string of numbers or is it line-oriented?

Comment: no my text file has 5 column in each line @DarkKnight

Comment: Yest, I want this. @Sujay

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are looking for is a [external sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) algorithm.
The algorithm consists in reading a large file to be sorted in chunks of data small enough to fit in main memory, sort each of the chunks, write them out to a temporary file, and finally combined the smaller subfiles into a single larger file. [Here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/External_sort#Python) you can find a python implementation that might be useful.

Comment: I want to sort the data with first two column among 5 column